# WCF Web service and timers

Tags: wcf

I'm planning to create a web service that will be hosted on IIS to handle reservations. One of the methods is

ReserveTimeSlot() which returns a reservationID to a client. The client has 2 minutes to confirm reservation or to cancel it. If it doesn't respond then after 2 minutes the reservation is cancelled. Reservations are stored in a database.

I'm not sure how can one implement a 2 minute timeout into a web service call. Helpful suggestions are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an acceptable solution for my case in this link

[WCF Service Application Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614358/wcf-service-application-timer)

The first tests are promising. Thanks for devoting time for my questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of possible solutions.

1. When reservationID is stored to DB store expiration date also, in your case DataTime expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
2. When client returns with reservationID you will need to check if reservationID exists and if is it still valid (DateTime.Now < expires)

Comment: what if the client never returns?

Comment: This is not a problem. Let's say you have stored procedure for reservationID validation. If you want you can extend this stored procedure with clean up of expired requests. This way you will delete all requests that has not been confirmed (client never returned) if you want.

Comment: The reservation needs to be cleared in exactly 2 minutes since only one reservation can occupy one time slot. I need a solution that will do that in exactly 2 minutest.

Comment: If you insist in timer concept then you will have to make wcf singleton (this is bad choice, killing wcf performance, possible state loose). Anyway here is link: http://wcftutorial.net/Singleton-Service.aspx Then in your single instance you will have to start new Thread or Task that will clear expired requests inside wcf application state. Here you can read about Threads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx and here about Tasks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: But in the end concept with state stored in db would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

At server end you can **save the id  in the database**  which you are sending to the client and as soon as the response is send you can start a timer which is associated with that Id in a new Thread.... that **thread will be suspended for 2 minutes** and after coming back will check the status from database and **if the user had not responded then this thread will  cancel the current request**

Comment: i forgot to mention database

Comment: I'm still not sure the thread is a good idea.  What if you have 1000 requests -- now you've spawned 1000 threads.  Doesn't seem vary economical.  Why not just keep a static ConcurrentDictionary with the expiration info instead?

Comment: What will clear reservation from static ConcurrentDictionary when a reservation expires?